# Is there any way to disable uBlock Origin popup from showing up?

Tags: ublock-origin

As part of distraction blocking setup I was searching the way on how to remove any options to disable or disrupt the functionality of extensions. Is there any way to disable the floating window uBlock Origin has in the top right corner or make it to open as a standalone link?

I am using Chrome. I want to not be able to disable uBlock for the page I am in from the floating popup window. So that either to remove the popup window, or to disable the "off" button, or to make this popup window open in URL.

I use blockers for URLs like Cold Turkey and FocusMe and I use uBlock to block youtube mixes. And I want to disable option to turn off uBlock for this intend in a popup window which I can't put a block on.

I know that it's possible to do because I removed in a chromium version source code manifest.json  this line  "page":

> "background.html"

and then stripped down popup-fenix.html to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blank Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

and basically that was it, I didn't have working popup window which is what I wanted. The question then became that I can't enforce my own extension for Chrome in any way, and can't publish it to myself.

uBlock Origin popup window:
[image: uBlock Origin popup window]

Comment: Try a different browser.  Put a push on and earn 100 points and then you will not be bothered with this.

Comment: That popup should only show when you click on the icon. Is that showing all the time for you? Or, are you trying to make it show up in a different way? Also, what browser are you doing this in?

Comment: I updated the question. I don't know what you mean John by this: "Put a push on and earn 100 points and then you will not be bothered with this.". To put a push on what and which points.

No, the popup shows when I click on it. I want to not have option to turn off uBlock for a page in this popup window which can't be blocked in any way. Either to disable this option to turn off, or to open it in a standalone chrome://extension/whatever page. I know this can be done by modifying source code, specifically manifest.json and popup-fenix.html, but I didn't find any option to do this in extension

Comment: "Put a push on"  means achieve 100 reputation points with very good questions and /or good answers.  This earns reputation points.  With a chromium based browser, I am not seeing any issues.

Comment: You can always fork and modify the extension, the install a local extension or publish your own fork to Google Chrome Store. Of course you'll be missing changes from regular uBlock Origin, unless you keep merging them from upstream.

Comment: I actually can't publish this extension anymore because it uses Manifest V2 and Chrome is dropping it's support for it, any new extensions must be Manifest V3. Installing a local extension is not an option for this as I wanted to force install it (to not be able to uninstall or modify it), and Chrome is not allowing it for my own extensions. But I actually made my own extension to block youtube mixes and waiting for it to be approved for Chrome extension store. I would want it to be enforced in Registry Editor.